# Sending email in php with inline images

Tags: php, image, email, inline

I am using php's built-in mail-function to send emails. So far I've accomplished a lot by looking at other examples and stripping what I thought would be necessary.

My current code for sending emails with inline images looks like this. The content is generated by using a template which may or may not have some placeholders which are replaced by values from my database (this is omitted)

```
function sendEmail($to, $subject, $htmlmessage, $inline_images = array()){   
   define('RN', "\n");
   /* define mime boundaries */
   $mime_boundary_mix = "_mix_" . md5(time());

   /* set headers */
   $headers = "From: info@domain.nl" . RN;
   $headers .= "Reply-To: info@domain.nl" . RN;
   $headers .= "Return-Path: info@otherdomain.nl" . RN;
   $headers .= "Message-ID: <".time()."_DOMAIN@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">" . RN;
   $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion() . RN;

   $headers .= "Mime-Version: 1.0" . RN;
   $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . RN;
   $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary_mix}\"";

   /* start email body with mime_boundary */
   $msg = "--{$mime_boundary_mix}" . RN;
   /* include html */
   $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-15\"". RN;
   $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit". RN . RN;
   $msg .= $htmlmessage . RN;

   /* check if there are inline images */
   if(count($inline_images) > 0) {
      foreach($inline_images as $image) {
         $path_to_image = $image['path'];
         $image_filename = basename($path_to_image);
         $image_type = filetype($path_to_image);

         $file_handler = fopen($path_to_image, 'rb');
         $image_data = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($file_handler, filesize($path_to_image))));
         fclose($file_handler);

         /* start mime boundary */
         $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary_mix}" . RN;
         /* add image data */
         $msg .= "Content-Type: {" . image_type_to_mime_type (exif_imagetype($path_to_image)) . "};" . RN;
         $msg .= " name=\"{$image_filename}\"" . RN;
         $msg .= "Content-Disposition: inline;" . RN;
         $msg .= " filename=\"{$image_filename}\"" . RN;
         $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . RN . RN;
         $msg .= $image_data . RN . RN;

      }
      /* end mime boundary */
      $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary_mix}--" . RN;

   }
   /* end mime boundary */
   $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary_mix}--" . RN;

   return mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
}
```

$inline_images is an array which contains items with paths to images like:
array([0] => array('path' => "myimage.png")) (if I'm not mistaken, but this is not important)

Can anybody tell me why using this code, Outlook puts an attachment icon with this e-mail and why gmail shows a warning: do you want to show all images and doesn't show any when I allow these?
A few questions about this:
- Receiving this e-mail in Outlook works fine, but I'd like to hide the paperclip icon if possible, afterall it's an embedded image and not really an attachment.
- In GMail I receive the e-mail with the images as attachments and blanks (broken image-icon) at the place of all images in the e-mail, how do I fix this? GMail asks me first if I want to allow the images, but after I allow the blanks show up. And can I also hide the images as attachments in GMail?
- I also tried viewing the e-mail in Office Outlook Web Access, which presented the e-mail in the same manner GMail did: images not shown, but only as attachments.

Can anyone help me with this?
If you need more details, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go for libraries like phpmailer or switmailer.? They provide full support for html mails. Also you won't need to create all the headers.

Comment: I myself would opt for something like PEAR, but it's not on my webhost, and I'm not in the position to swap webhosts.

Comment: I didn't use PEAR for mailing. Why you need to swap webhosts.? you can simply use this libraries, without any external dependencies.